# Circumventing eval

Tags: javascript, eval

I have code listed in a table and I want to access code in a certain cell and run it. The problem is that all values in the table are strings and I can't convert strings into code.

```
function readTable(tableName, rowId, columnName) {
 readRecords(tableName, {}, function(records) {
   for (var i =0; i < records.length; i++) {
    var record = records[i];
      if (record.id === rowId) {
      if (record[columnName]!==undefined) {
          eval(record[columnName]);
      }
      }
   }
 }); 
}
```

Is there any way to get around using eval? For example, the text in one of my table cells is intepreted as (after saving the table)

```
"setText(\"specialbutton\",\"You got tricked. Be careful next time.\");gameovercounter()"
```

and it runs as

```
setText("specialbutton","You got tricked. Be careful next time.");gameovercounter()
```

after using eval. I haven't figured out how to avoid eval in this instance.

Comment: does the code have to be stored in a table?

Comment: Just to be clear, it's a html table? If so, don't save literal JS code inside the DOM, use event names that correspond with a function, so that reading the string and calling the respective function is not coupled to eachother.

Comment: can you store commands and parameters in the table instead? like `setText,   "string1", "string2"`?

Comment: If you are forced to work with a setup like this, than eval is IMO the best tool you have for the job

Comment: If you have some kind of DSL which is similar to JS then maybe you can use a parser library, get the expression tree, and create JS code based on that. `eval` is dangerous if used without trying to strip the potential dangerous parts from the string. So, can you describe the code syntax that is allowed in your string?

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm mostly using variable reassignments (x--, y++, z=5 etc.) and setText in my tables. I'm not putting large amounts of code into table cells, just snippets here and there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to avoid eval and still run code from text is to use:

```
new Function(strFuncBody)
```

Replace your eval code with:

```
if (record[columnName]!==undefined) {
    // create a function to run
    var func = new Function(record[columnName]);
    // then call the function...
    func();
}
```

There is a big difference between eval() and Function(), explained in the section called *"Do not ever use eval!"* in this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval.

**Regardless, you should never run strings as code using new Function() or eval() if you do not have complete control over what the string contains.**

Comment: "Regardless, you should never run strings as code ... if you do not have complete control over what the string contains." Sorry. I should've made it clear that I have complete control over the string themselves and only use the table to store them. The table is not being filled by user input. Anyways, nice answer.